# Ember CLI Testing with ic-ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, ember.js

I'm having trouble acceptance testing an Ember CLI Component that uses ic-ajax to submit a form.

The problem is that the `andThen` function in the acceptance test doesn't wait for the form submission to resolve.

Component:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import ajax from 'ic-ajax';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'form',

  // ...snip...

  submit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const request = ajax({
      url: "url.com"
    });
    // Debugging in test mode, Ember.Test.lastPromise === null here?
  }

  // ...snip...

});
```

Acceptance Test:

```
test('it surfaces errors', function(assert) {
  visit('/test');
  let component;

  andThen(function() {
    component = find('.my-form');

    fillIn('input[Placeholder="Email"]', 'not@valid');
    click('button[type="submit"]');    

    andThen(function() {
      // PROBLEM: This code doesn't wait for the ic-ajax promise to resolve
      assert.ok(component.hasClass('error'), "The component applied the error classname.");
    });
  });
});
```

Creating the `ic-ajax` promise doesn't seem to set `Ember.Test.lastPromise`, meaning `andThen` doesn't wait for the form submit to return.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it happens because submit action in your component performs an asynchronous request to the server. Basically it runs in another "thread", in parallel with the main programm flow. So `andThen` helper knows nothing about it. Try to `return` the request object promise out of `sumbit` action so that `andThen` helper could catch and handle it.

If this won't help, you could also make this ajax request run synchronously for test environment.